# How aosp build a aar file?

Tags: android, android-source, aar, android-soong

I want to build a aosp project(SystemUI) with Android studio. But it dependency some libs (e.g. SettingsLib), I know the settingslib is build by android_library. So how do build the settingsLib to a aar format file, then I can import it to android studio?

Comment: Hi, have you checked the official documentation https://source.android.com/devices/audio/implement-shared-library?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The documentation that you share instroduces how build a jar file with gnu make system, it's not the answer i want. I build my project with soong system, and i has checked https://source.android.com/setup/build and https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/7299567/linux/latest/view/soong_build.html, but did not find a way to build an aar file.

Comment: @Jannicus did you manage to build .aar file using soong/make?